# Combine rxjs streams, detect changes and return one value

Tags: javascript, typescript, .net-core, rxjs, ngrx

The background - Angular + .net Core WebApi, let's say I'm building a time management app to track how much time you spent on tasks -> user creates a task on frontend and starts it -> there is a timer showing elapsed time.

The idea - the elapsed time is coming from backend. When the user starts a task on frontend through service I start a timer on backend and passing elapsed time back to frontend so I can show it to the user. I want to show the correct value even if there is a connection issue between the backend and frontend.

Diagram: backend stream emits value every second (elapsed time that I show to the user) but there is a connection glitch and after 6 seconds it freezes for a moment and then sends 9 ("0:09") which may confuse user ("was 6 seconds and now it's 9??"). So I create and interval on the frontend that emits new value every second. Every second I want to check if backend stream sent new value and if not I want to get previous value and modify it so user gets correct value.

```
bStream => ---1---2---3---4---5---6---x---x---9
fStream => ---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9

What user sees:
00:01 -> 00:02 -> 00:03 -> 00:04 -> 00:05 -> 00:06 (freeze) -> 00:09

What I want to user to see:
00:01 -> 00:02 -> 00:03 -> 00:04 -> 00:05 -> 00:06 -> (freeze - frontend knows there is no new value so adds 1 second to previous)
So, it should look like that:
00:01 -> 00:02 -> 00:03 -> 00:04 -> 00:05 -> 00:06 -> 00:07 -> 00:08 -> 00:09
```

I'm struggling where to start.

Made quick fiddle with two streams but can't get my head around how to find it bStream did not emit new value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yookbj

Comment: why not taking elapsed time on frontend?

Answer (score 2):

plese check the code below. to simulate sync issue change the code `v * 5` to `v * 4`, then counter will respect the value from the "backend" once has got it.

```js
// emit every 5s
const source = interval(5000).pipe(
    map(v1 => v1 + 1), // <- only for the example. starting counting from 1.
    startWith(0), // <- only for the example. instant emit of 0.

    map(v => v * 5), // <- every 5 seconds we get right passed amount. so it emits 0 5 10 15.
);
// emit every 1s
const secondSource = interval(1000).pipe(
    delay(50), // <- we want it to be a bit later than original counter.
    map(v1 => v1 + 1), // emits are 1 2 3, not from 0.
    startWith(0), // instant emit of 0.
);

source.pipe( // <- it is our slow backend (it gives us an update every 5 seconds.
    switchMap(v => secondSource.pipe( // if no emit from parent stream - then in 1.05 we get value from this one.
        map(v1 => v + v1), // - adding offset from the second stream to the parent stream.
    )),
).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

now it counts smoothly from 0 to N even there're lags from the backend.

***UPDATED***

there's even simpler way, but the problem is that it doesn't rely on time when backend answered and has own 1 second period.

```js
pipe(
  bufferTime(1000), // <- collects for a second.
  scan((a, b) => b.length ? a + 1 : b[0], 0), // assumes or returns.
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```js
const be$ = concat(
  of(1).pipe(delay(100)),
  of(2).pipe(delay(100)),
  of(3).pipe(delay(100)),
  of(4).pipe(delay(100)),
  of(5).pipe(delay(100)),
  of(6).pipe(delay(100)),

  of(10).pipe(delay(500)), // After freeze
  of(11).pipe(delay(100)),
  of(12).pipe(delay(100)),
).pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true, }), endWith(null));

// `skip(1)` - the `ReplaySubject` used be `shareReplay()` will give us the latest value
// and it's not needed
const beReady$ = be$.pipe(skip(1), take(1));

const fe$ = be$.pipe(
  mergeMap(v => merge(
    of(v),
    of(v).pipe(
      expand(v => timer(100).pipe(map(v1 => 1 + v))),
      takeUntil(beReady$),
    )
  )),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  filter(v => v !== null)
).subscribe(console.log)
```

`endWith(null)` - in order to stop the recursion when the last value(`12`) is emitted, we need the source to emit something else

`shareReplay` - the source needs to be shared as there will be another subscriber(`beReady$`), besides the *main subscriber*(`fe$`)

```js
mergeMap(v => merge(
  of(v), // Pass along the current value
  of(v).pipe(
    // If the `be$` does not emit in the next 100ms, send the `currentValue + 1`
    // and keep doing the same until the `be$` finally emits
    expand(v => timer(100).pipe(map(v1 => 1 + v))),
    takeUntil(beReady$),
  )
)),
```

`expand` is like using `mergeMap`, but:

- it will pass along the inner value
- it will create **another inner observable** based on the last inner value; so, it's recursive
- `takeUntil(beReady$)` is how the recursion can be stopped

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeout-example?file=index.ts)

Comment: should it be so complicated? switchMap and a small delay do the same much easier.

Comment: I thought it was a good use case for `expand`. However, I agree, `switchMap` would simplify things.

Comment: as a use case, it is :) a nice operator. Sorry for the offtopic.

Comment: No worries! You were right, for some reason ‘swtichMap’ didn’t came to mind